# Issue with autosize input and it's neighbor input

Tags: jquery, css, input, autosize

Hi Please see a link below.

https://jsfiddle.net/bigevent/t8xukung/

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child-a">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" class="name" placeholder="Name:" data-autosize-input='{ "space": 40 }' />
</div>
<div class="child-b">
    <input name="email" placeholder="Email:" class="email">
</div>
```

I made two inputs side by side. First one(name) is resizing depending on the length of the text. Second one(email) has min-width so when the name becomes wider than 50%, the email moves down to the next line. And I find two issues.

First issue is that when email input moves down, it does not cover the whole width and stays as 50% which is its min-width. Is there any way to fix it so that the email covers the whole width when it moves down below.

Second issue is that the name gets longer than the parent boundary, it goes beyond the box. Is there way to stop within the parent boudary?

You can see from the image below what it looks like when you the name gets wider than the parent and email does not cover the whole width.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post your code directly to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this is a hack since we dont want to edit the autosize plugin

Add to CSS

```
.big {
    width:100% !important;
    clear:both;
}
.big > input{
    width:100% !important;
}
```

Add to JS

```
setInterval(function(){
   if( $('.child-a > input').width()>$('.child-a').parent().width()/2){
    $('.child-a,.child-b').addClass('big');
   }else{
     $('.child-a,.child-b').removeClass('big');
   }
},200);
```

Do forget about the media queries they work when you resize or show your webapp on different device height and width.

Comment: That is amazing. It is good to learn that I can add class with js. One thing I would like to ask is if that is possible with percent not px for the width. If you go to my jsfiddle link, percent value does not work. Do you have any clue? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: yup edited code. Should work on %s now. Please if this is the answer can you accept the answer here

Comment: Thank you so much. You are genious.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS @media queries

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {

    input.email{
        width:100% !important;
    }
}
```

This will be executed when the device width ranges from 320-480 px all general phones should cover that, else you can also do when you drag and resize your browser.

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px) {}
```

These are called CSS media queries and you can read about them here [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: I just showed you the way, from your fiddle when I resize the box stays the same size, maybe try on the parent div or something, ie your fiddle is not responsive. The email input never came to the next line for me.

Comment: If you try again from the link above, you can probably see the email input come to the next line when you add text in the name input. I just learned t hat it works fine with Firefox when email input goes down. But the name input still goes beyond the parent.